# Making a keyboard shortcut using the Fn (function) key on OS X

Tags: keyboard

A lot of my use for Mathematica is creating notebooks that read like textbooks.  For this reason, most of my time is spent in text cells.  As I type in a text cell, I am constantly creating inline cells.  I find the Control + 9 method for creating an inline cell annoying, difficult and time consuming.

I'm hoping to use the Fn key on the lower left-hand side of the keyboard instead of having to type Control + 9.  This would be easier because its one key and its easy to get to.  On top of that, I never use the Fn key for anything... so its available.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I know its possible.  I've tried using modifying keyeventtranslations. Currently I have the following code in keyeventtranslations.nb

```
Item[KeyEvent["9", Modifiers -> {Control}], "CreateInlineCell"]
```

It seems it would be easy to do what I want if I knew the keyevent for the Fn key.  But I don't.  I don't think Mathematica recognizes this key at all for some reason.  I can't seem to find it anywhere in the documentation either.  So this leads to a dead end as far as I can tell.

Do you have any advice on go about going this another way?

Comment: Does `Item[KeyEvent["F9"], ...]` (for the function key 9) work? Looking at the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, it seems to be done this way. (I did not try it myself.)

Comment: No this doesn't work either.  I don't think Mathematica recognizes the functions keys at all.  I'm thinking there is probably a way hack this by creating a hot key in OS X settings that creates a character which Mathematica recognizes which then turns into  "CreateInlineCell".  Kind of a shortcut to a shortcut to the solution.  But I can't figure it out.

Comment: I just tried it on Windows and it doesn't work as well. I tried also with a few modifiers but without success. I can see at the end of the file `"F1"` and `"F2"` being used, and I interpreted the former as the shorcut for opening the documentation center. Now I am seeing that this is `SelectionHelpDialog[False]` and not the token [`"SelectionHelpDialog"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/frontendobject/SelectionHelpDialog.html), so maybe this is for another thing. I am not sure how one can get the function keys to work, which could be really nice indeed.

Comment: This may not be possible, at least not directly in Mathematica.  This is a very special modifier that is used to type keys that are not physically present on a laptop keyboard.  Mathematica probably isn't even able to see this as a separate key.  I mean that when you type Fn-Down, it probably sees it as the same PgDn as the one you could type on a large keyboard having a separate PgDn key.  It probably doesn't see it as Down with the Fn modifier.

Comment: Ok.  What about the caps lock key?  Can I edit keyeventtranslations.nb to make the caps lock key create inline cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MacOS system preferences you can assign any shortcut to a menu item. You can do that for "Start Inline Cell" (^9) and assign it to whichever key you like.

Function keys can be touchy though, you may find that apps like *FunctionFlip* and *Karabiner-Elements* will help.

Here is one way to go about it:

1. In *[Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements)* assign the **Fn** key to some unused key (I tried Keypad_9 as my Macbook does not have a keypad)
2. Then in system preferences assign "*Start Inline Cell*" to
   Keypad_9 (by pressing **Fn**)

That is is! You can probably do this with the caps-lock key just as well.